# Composer package maatwebsite/excel requires Libzip4, but it's installed

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, zip

So I'm working on a project solo, and I wanted to export table data into CSV.
So I went with this composer package:

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

The terminal  outputs this:

```
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.9.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
```

So I searched around for answers including here and I tried the following:
I followed the  answer provided
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/933074/attempting-to-install-php-zip-getting-libzip4-dependancy-1-0-error-even-th).

I tried installing libzip4, I get this:

```
libzip4 is already the newest version (1.1.2-1.1pop2).
```

I tried installing libzip5 for which I got:

```
libzip5 is already the newest version (1.5.1-0ubuntu1).
```

So I tried installing php7.3-zip  package: for which I get this:

```
php7.3-zip : Depends: libzip4 (>= 1.3.2) but 1.1.2-1.1pop2 is to be installed
```

Which is wierd and I'm stuck!

Simply installing doing sudo apt-get install  php-zip  gives me this error:

```
 php-zip : Depends: php7.3-zip but it is not going to be installed
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

What should I do guys? I have Pop OS and i haven't faced any PHP 7.3 related issues so far.

Comment: Can you check it by install gd library for php 7.3 by this command 

apt install php7.3-gd

Comment: Yes It's installed: php7.3-gd is already the newest version (7.3.9-1+ubuntu19.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).

Comment: I got it fixed guys: I got the Debian 10 package of libzip4 (1.5). Should I use this debian 10 package or not recommended? I'm using Pop os

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions you can do is delete the `composer.lock` file and then do a `composer install` and `composer update`.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm doing  this even the same for package-json.lock and deleting node_modules and redoing npm install. Let's  see  if php-zip gets fixed.